# V8 HeapGraphNode and HeapGraphEdge Types

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, v8

I am working on a memory inspection tool for Node.js and have been using `HeapSnapshot` to collect and walk the object graph.

A few of the [object types](http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1HeapGraphNode.html#ab674a58103a51abc56f99edc6a1479ed) are straight-forward to understand, such as `kObject` or `kArray`. I am looking for more information on `kHidden`.

According to the [V8 Design Documents](https://developers.google.com/v8/design), javascript objects are given hidden classes, to speed up property access. Are these related to the above `kHidden` property?